# Java Servlet @Override Annotation

Tags: java, servlets

Should I add `@Override` annotation when overriding `doGet()` and `doPost()` methods from `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`?

For example:

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        /* my code */
    }
}
```

I've never seen code that adds `@Override` annotation to servlet code.

Comment: Yes, you should always use `@Override` when you can, to document that you are overriding a method, and to guard against not overriding because you got the argument types wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `@Override`.  It helps catch errors where something has caused the class being extended to change.